# Printing pay bill in Crystal Report C#

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

I want to print pay bill using Crystal Report. I am new to it and do not know how to use it the best way. I have a table which have following columns linked to crystal report:-

```
   [Year]  
  ,[Month]  
  ,[Emp_Id]  
  ,[Emp_Name]  
  ,[Department]  
  ,[Pay_Head_Id]  
  ,[Pay_Head_Name]  
  ,[Pay_Head_Type]  
  ,[Amount]
```

I want that for each employee pay head name and amount must be printed one after the other and line break once it reach end of the row.

Kindly find the image of the pay bill and let me know how can I do it. I am unable to print them in the row and also lacking in how to use queries.
Image:
![Pay bill]http://prminfotech.com/paybill1.JPG

Comment: In CR, create a group for the Emp_Name field, and add the other values you wish to the DETAIL section.

Comment: I really hope that you are not using actual employee data.

Comment: @astander, why did you answer the question as a comment?

Comment: @craig, I did not see that the comment I left was a full answer, but merely a point in the direction required.

Answer (score -1):

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\abdozezo\Documents\Database10.accdb");

string query = "SELECT *  FROM   Table1";

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

adp.Fill(dt);

CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();

cr1.SetDataSource(dt);

// cr1.Load(@"CrystalReport1.rpt"); for dire`enter code here`ct upload 

viewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = cr1;//viewer is crystal report
```